# SimpleJpaRepository does not modify persisted entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

When I'm persisting an entity with `SimpleJpaRepository#save()` it will not modify it. E.g. it will not set the new id of the entity.

Apart from that, everything works fine. The entity is being persisted and given an id. If I read it from the database I can see the id. Is this normal behavior? I know the #save method returns the persisted entity but I would prefer it to modify the given entity. Is there a way of configuring this?

Thanks

-- edit

Let's assume this is what I do:

```
User user = new User();
// do something with user

userRepository.save(user);
```

Then `user` stays the same. The object *is* written to the database but user does not become managed. Also `saveAndFlush(user)` will not result in different behavior. What I can do is `user = userRepository.save(user)`. In this case user becomes the managed instance. But from Hibernate I'm used to just save the object and my submitted object becomes managed. Is there a way of archieving this with JPA?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `@Id` configuration in the Entity. Please make sure you have correctly defined `@GeneratedValue` on the `Id` attribute. This attribute plays a key role in differentiating between `insert` and `update` operations.

Comment: Thanks but as I said, the id is assigned, the entity is saved and if I read it from the database again, I can see the id. This just doesn't happen automatically after `.save()`

Comment: @entek Try `saveAndFlush`. It will flush the changes immediately and your return object should have the Id, populated.

Comment: I updated my original post so my problem should be more clear.